# "married to someone" VS "married someone"

Tags: expressions

Both of them are correct, aren't they?

> She has married an architect.
>
> She has married to an architect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, "She has married to an architect" is not idiomatic English.

In present-day English *married to* is employed most often as an adjective:

> She **is** married to an architect.

It will occasionally be found as the passive of transitive *marry X to Y*, where the Agent of *marry* is neither X nor Y but some third party.

> The Rev. Arbuckle married Susan Jones to William Smith.
>   The Joneses have married their daughter Susan to Bill Smith.
>   Susan Jones was married to William Smith last Sunday.
>   Susan got married to Bill last Sunday.

Present perfect *has married ... to Y* can only be the active voice of this transitive *marry*; it requires a direct object, and a subject who is neither of the two people who get married.

You **can** however write:

> She has married an architect,

without *to*—this is a different transitive idiom meaning she became the architect's wife.

Comment: great explanation

Comment: I'm writing to you in order to find the answer to my question. You've been recommended as a specialist in the area my question belongs too. Please, take a lool at the following link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136093/past-perfect-vs-past-simple-in-the-context-of-previous-experience?noredirect=1#comment275306_136093

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov Present perfect often alternates with simple past, depending on where you want to put your focus. Check out our tag wiki on [Tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/tense/info) and my post on the [Perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it); then let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand you correctly, but I think you haven't understand me yet. I've already read you post. I still don't know the answer, though. I want to know why I can't use Past Perfect in the first example and why "war" isn't a reference time. My arguments have been represented in the penultimate comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136093/past-perfect-vs-past-simple-in-the-context-of-previous-experience?noredirect=1#comment275306_136093